# How to connect zookeeper using sarama go client?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sarama

I am a beginner at using the sarama client. Although my code is working fine with the bootstrap servers but unable to connect with the zookeepers.

**kafka node version:** confluent-kafka-2.11-0.10.2.1-2.noarch
**sarama client version:** v1.38.0

```
config := kafka.NewConfig()
broker := []string{"localhost:9092"}
kafkaClient, err := kafka.NewClusterAdmin(broker, config)
```

Error:
**kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: EOF**

Answer (score 0):

Your error simply says **Kafka** isn't running at the host:port you've provided, and has nothing to do with Zookeeper

---

Sarama is a **Kafka client**. You should not be using it to connect to Zookeeper.

If you need to execute Zookeeper operations, you will need a different library, but you should never need Zookepeer operations for a Kafka application. `KafkaAdminClient` will forward any requests to Zookeeper, if it needs to (unless you run Kafka in Kraft mode, where Zookeeper isn't used).